# Timestamp does not work with built in variables

Tags: pine-script

If I hard code the date/time into the timestamp (in line 3), that day's open is plotted as I would expect. However, using trading view's built-in variables (commented out in line 4), nothing is plotted. I cant understand the difference, maybe I'm not using the built-in variables correctly.

I did a test to see if the built-in variables matched the hard-coded values and from what I saw, they did match.

```
//@version=4

study( "Session Open", overlay = true)

t = timestamp(2019, 8, 30, 9, 30)

//t = timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth, 9, 30)

l = float(na)
l := time >= t and na(l[1]) ? open : l[1]

plot(l)
```

Assuming you hard code the current date into line 3, I would expect lines 3 and 4 to properly create a timestamp that can be used to plot the open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables `year`, `month` and `dayofthemonth` return their information relative to the bar the script is running on. *Today* for them, is the date of the bar—not what *today* means to you.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I was using these variables wrong. I did not realize they were relative to the bar. Thankyou!